Github Classroom CLI Clone Student Repositories not working
My students have submitted their assignments, and I am going to grade them.  Previously, I had been cloning one at a time, but I just noticed that I can clone the entire set of them at once.  I went to do so, and discovered that I needed the GH CLI to do so.  I installed gh and authenticated, and chose ssh as my preferred authentication method (my github key is already on this computer).  I then executed the following command:
$ gh classroom clone student-repos -a XXXXXX
and received the following error:
Cloning into: /home/rob/submissions/someones_assignment
2024/06/18 20:07:28 could not find gh executable in PATH. error: exec: "gh": executable file not found in $PATH

First of all, gh is certainly in my path.  It was snap installed and the snap folder is in the path. I am able to directly invoke gh, but it seems that this classroom function is not able to do so.  I tried manually setting the path and that did not help.  Any help to get this working would be greatly appreciated.
